# Senior Manager of Employee sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an employee table:

[image: Employee]

I have a category table which joins userid and category id:

[image]

Category with value 1 is senior manager.

I want to find senior manager of each employee.Seniors Managers with category value of 1.

I need the output like this:

[image]

How can we achieve this in SQL Server 2008?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As this query calls for a [Self Join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490(v=sql.105).aspx), this should work:

```
 SELECT a.EMPLOYEENAME as Employee,
        b.EMPLOYEENAME as Senior_Manager
 FROM employee a
 LEFT JOIN
 employee b ON a.ID = b.Manager
 LEFT JOIN
 category c ON b.ID = c.UserID
 WHERE c.Category = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
WITH Emp_CTE AS (

 Select ID,EmployeeName,Manager from employee

 UNION ALL

 SELECT ecte.ID,ecte.EmployeeName,c.Manager
 FROM employee c
 INNER JOIN Emp_CTE ecte ON ecte.Manager = c.ID
)
SELECT a.ID,a.EmployeeName,b.EmployeeName
FROM Emp_CTE a
left join employee b
on a.Manager = b.ID
left join category c
on a.Manager = c.UserID
where c.Category = '1'
```